# Recursive search JSON/DICT in Python 3

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I am realizing in Python 3 some APIs that allow me to receive information about a school based on the class code. But I would like to know how I get the information through the class code.
Example:
I enter the code `GF528S` and I want the program to tell me the class (`3C INF`), the address (`Address 1, Milan`), and if possible also the name of the school (`Test School 1`) and the previous keys. Thanks in advance! Of course I use a JSON structure:

```
{
    "schools": {
         "Lombardia": {
            "Milano": {
                "Milano": {
                    "Test School 1": {
                        "sedi": {
                            "0": {
                                "indirizzo": "Address 1, Milan",
                                "classi": {
                                    "INFORMATICA E TELECOMUNICAZIONI": {
                                        "3C INF": "GF528S"
                                    }                                    
                                }
                            },
                            "1": {
                                "indirizzo": "Address 2, Milan",
                                "classi": {
                                    "INFORMATICA E TELECOMUNICAZIONI": {
                                        "1A IT": "HKPV5P", 
                                        "2A IT": "QL3J3K",
                                        "3A INF": "X4E35C",
                                        "3A TEL": "ZAA7LC"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

When I get the values ​​from my database they are converted to a python dictionary if it helps!
After a series of tests thanks to your answers, I found that the `for in .items()` is blocked when it shows the `indirizzo` field:
In particular, it cannot search in these dictionaries:

```
{'classi': {'INFORMATICA E TELECOMUNICAZIONI': {'3C INF': 'GF528S'}}, 'indirizzo': 'Address 1, Milan'}
{'classi': {'INFORMATICA E TELECOMUNICAZIONI': {'1A IT': 'HKPV5P', '2A IT': 'QL3J3K', '3A INF': 'X4E35C', '3A TEL': 'ZAA7LC'}}, 'indirizzo': 'Address 2, Milan'}
```

I think the problem is precisely the `indirizzo` field. If you want to do the for first, it can be saved in a variable and deleted from the json:

```
del val ["address"]
```

The problem is that then I can't associate the address with the class.
Code:

```
def dictionary_check(input):
    indirizzo = ""
    for key,value in input.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            dictionary_check(value)
        else:
            for i in value:
                indirizzo += i["indirizzo"]
                del i['indirizzo']
                for x, y in i.items():
                    for z, j in y.items():
                        for a in j.items():
                            if a[1] == "HKPV5P":
                                print(indirizzo)
                                print("Classe: " + a[0])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Yes, in a nutshell I'm asking someone to do this, or explain to me how I could navigate the json file, but obviously before creating this question, I searched and tried various codes, without success. In fact, I wanted someone to help me understand how to perform a recursive search. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should use recursive function to find key or value.

```
def search_key(data, key, path=""):
    if type(data) is  dict:
        for k, v in data.items():
            path="{0} -> {1}".format(path, k)
            if k == key or v == key:
                return (k, v, path)
            res = search_key(data[k], key, path)
            if res is not None:
                return res

result = search_key(your_dictionary, key="GF528S")
if result is not None:
    print("key:", result[0])
    print("value:", result[1])
    print("path:", result[2])
else:
    print("key or value not found!")
```

If you want to search entire of dictionary and get all duplicate keys or values using given pattern key, this below function is useful.

```
def entire_search_key(data, key, founds=[], path=""):
    if type(data) is  dict:
        for k, v in data.items():
            path="{0} -> {1}".format(path, k)
            if k == key or v == key:
                founds.append((k, v, path))
            entire_search_key(data[k], key, founds, path)
    return founds

result = entire_search_key(your_dictionary, key="ddd")
if result == []:
    print("key or value not found!")
else:    
    for i in result:
        print(i)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in both codes, by entering `GF528S` as a value, nothing is found and or discovered that at some point, from dictionary it is transformed into a list:
`<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'list'>`
key or value not found!
I would need more information from the value (`GF528S`)

Comment: Add        yourdictionary = {"schools": {"Lombardia": { ...        in top of that functions in your code and try again. Variable yourdictionary  is your sample dictionary in question post above.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't write the exact code for you, I think it's reasonable to be able to give you a rough idea of what the code would look like, and some guidance.

I don't exactly know where this JSON data is being obtained. So it may have more / less keys when your applications runs. However, assuming the json is exactly as is, and the json data is loaded onto the variable (let's say json_map), then accessing a specific value looks something like:

```
json_map[key_value]
```

So you would want to do something similar to

```
json_map['schools']['Lombardia']['Milano']
```

and more keys until you reach the dictionary you want to play around with.

I think the point you might be confused is - if you have multiple values (that you may not be aware of what they might look like) how you handle it. For example, I think the key "sedi" (which I assume means locations) might return multiple locations (i.e. schools) and you won't know what their keys / values are. In that case, you may wish to iterate through that dictionary via something like:

```
for key, value in dict_.items():
    # do your action
```

it is likely that key will be an integer (in string format) and value will be another dictionary. You will want to check a specific attribute of the dictionary to see if it's the one you're looking for.

Also, finally, when you get to the 'INFORMATICA E TELECOMUNICAZIONI' dictionary of the location(s), you may wish to return the key of the item that has the corresponding value. Something like:

```
for key, value in dict_.items():
    if value == 'GF528S':
        return key
```

Of course, you'll be able to replace this value of 'GF528S' to a variable so you can change it each time.

I think this is as far as I can help you without actually implementing this. I gave the benefit of the doubt that you are like me when I just started programming and I just needed someone to give me a rough outline of what to do. Any more help, I think you may need grab someone who has knowledge of what to do IRL or hire a tutor/teacher to teach you basic concepts of Programming.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already knew the for with the items of a dictionary, in fact using various for I was able to get the value and the key. My doubt is about how to get some keys (`Address 1, Milan` and `Test School 1`) corresponding to the value (`GF528S`). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
search_key = "GF528S"
def recursive_search(dct,keys):
    for key,value in dct.items():
        if key == search_key:
            print(keys,value)
        if type(value) == dict:
            recursive_search(value,[*keys,key])
recursive_search(dinput_dict,[])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just tried the code and it gives no results. I found that JSON from dictionary is later transformed into list. Through some prints, I found that it stops here:
`{'classi': {'INFORMATICA E TELECOMUNICAZIONI': {'3C INF': 'GF528S'}}, 'indirizzo': 'Address 1, Milan'}`
`{'classi': {'INFORMATICA E TELECOMUNICAZIONI': {'1A IT': 'HKPV5P', '2A IT': 'QL3J3K', '3A INF': 'X4E35C', '3A TEL': 'ZAA7LC'}}, 'indirizzo': 'Address 2, Milan'}`